# Echo the number of users using WP_User_Query?

Tags: wp-user-query

Ok, so right now I can easily echo the number of posts that has a specific `meta_key` and `meta_value`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array( 
        'meta_key' => 'usp-custom-1', 
        'meta_value' => get_permalink() 
    ) 
); 
echo $query->found_posts;
```

I'm trying to do something similar except for echoing the number of users that has a specific user_meta data.

I'm trying this:

```
$query = new WP_User_Query( 
    array(  
        'meta_key' => 'cash_out_status',  
        'meta_value' => 'pending' 
    ) 
); 
echo $query->found_users;
```

But the above doesn't display anything.

I guess I'm making a mistake somewhere in the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try adding  `'meta_compare' => '=',` to your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the public properties:

```
WP_Query->found_posts
WP_Comment_Query->found_comments
WP_Network_Query->found_networks
WP_Site_Query->found_sites
```

but then comes this private property (that's also made public via magic getter):

```
WP_User_Query::$total_users
```

but not `found_users` as expected, so the confusion is natural :-)

Look into the public `get_total()` method and the `count_total` bool attribute (true by default) in the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#total-count-parameter).

Comment: Thanks! Changing my code from `$query->found_users` to `$query->get_total()` did the job! Thanks again for your time and effort, birgire!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @robert0